# Badge progress status "review 0 more"

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, badge-progress, review-badges

I got the Reviewer badge a month ago, but I still see the message "review 0 more posts to earn the Reviewer badge". In contrast, Custodian badge was shown as granted when I have reviewed one item but did not get the badge in my profile at that moment.

> [image: Badge Progress: Review 0 more]

Comment: Then why the badge is granted? This reminds me the story when bank was sending notes to the client: "You have to pay your debt $0.00" each week. I believe this is because the real debt amount was $0.000001 which is of course non-zero from bank point of view. However both these messages look weird from end-user point of view.

Comment: I completely missed the fact that the badge was granted (realized only after re-reading). I need more, or less coffee - I'm not sure which.

Comment: @TimPost I saw that you have removed your comment, but I was so glad to recall this bank story so I just couldn't delete mine as well :)

Comment: It was that very story I was thinking of, but it was a mobile phone company instead of a bank. I think we can just combine them into one children's bedtime story called *the float that cried zero*

Comment: Someone used `>` to check the number instead of `>=` :o Who did it!? We want names!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, edge case - blame assigned which is the most important part. A fix will go out with the next build.

Comment: I'll wait for next build then. When it will be online?

Comment: We just built all sites.